# Chrome lags and runs up CPU usage

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, firefox, google-chrome

I have a Dell 7559 core i7 (67 machine and after spending some time I got Ubuntu 16.04 up and running. However for some reason beyond me chrome and firefox is laggy and choppy. Really frustrating!! I then had a look and it appears that the CPU usage grows to 100 percent when scrolling...

The machine has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz processor and a GTX 960M graphics card.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/798743/plymouth-causes-multiple-issues-with-16-04-lts-its-not-firefox-or-chrome-or-yo

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: really after all these years and I am struggling to scroll in a browser. Truly amazing

Comment: Turning off hardware acceleration fixed this issue for me. For Chrome go to settings > search for "hardware" > tick off [ ] Use hardware acceleration when available. Same setting is somewhere in FFx.

Comment: @wickd I can't believe it either... This is just insane.

Comment: @zwinny I tried that and it did not work. Suspect it has something to do with  the nvidia drivers. different versions result in different bugs. Some lag some chop etc etc.